# merge sort algorithm implemented in java giving ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

ive rewritten it a hundred times, i keep getting an IndexOutOfBound exception.
It may be an issue if the first for loop that fills in the left array, but im not sure how to change the logic.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 10
at mergeSortWithTwist.merge(mergeSortWithTwist.java:57)

i don't know what else to do, any help is appreciated !

```
public static void merge(int[] inputArr, int p, int q, int r) {

       int n1 = q-p+1;
       int n2 = r-q;
       int[] leftHalf = new int[n1];
       int[] rightHalf = new int[n2];

       for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
           leftHalf[i] = inputArr[p+i-1];

       for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
           rightHalf[i] = inputArr[q+i];

       leftHalf[n1+1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
       rightHalf[n2+1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

       int i = 0;
       int j = 0;
   

       for(int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
           if(leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j]){
               inputArr[k] = leftHalf[i];
               i++;
           }
           else {
               inputArr[k] = rightHalf[j];
               j++;
           }
       }

   }

    public static void merge_sort(int[] inputArr, int p, int r) {
        if(p<r) {
            int q = (p + r) / 2;
            merge_sort(inputArr,p,q);
            merge_sort(inputArr,q+1,r);
            merge(inputArr,p,q,r);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Repeatedly rewriting the same code is not the right way to fix your code.  The key word "debugging".  I suggest you read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: hey Stephen, thank you. can you please help direct me on how i might try to identify the bug?

Comment: What is line 57 in your sopurce code?

Comment: Hey! thank you so much for helping! its:           leftHalf[i] = inputArr[p+i-1];

Comment: Debugging is a useful skill. If you want to become a software developer, or otherwise create code, it will be a necessary skill. A debugger will allow you to set a break point, at which program execution will pause, allowing you to examine variables at that point. You could then continue program execution one-step-at-a-time while monitoring variables.

Comment: Then `p+i-1` is being evaluated to `-1` at some point.

Comment: This is a common question at Stack Overflow. You might answers to this question helpful:   [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Old Dog P! ill try to debug it  :)

Comment: Don't write, never publish/commit undocumented/uncommented code! From the signature of `merge()`, I can sort of guess where the output goes and what `r` is - *right*, the end of one sub-array to merge. But is `r` the index of the first element not to merge, or the last one to handle? To find out about `p` and `q`, looking at the "one" call site isn't promising the whole picture: `merge()` is `public`. Inspecting `merge()`'s code isn't promising considering it is stated to misbehave. And what if the right half contains `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? Document or fix! (Fix is as simple as it is ugly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

- `leftHalf[n1+1] =`  assigns to an out of range index. `leftHalf` has `n1` entries, so `n1+1` and even `n1` are out of range.
- The values `n1` and `n2` are determined by the size of the left and right partitions, which is fine, but as you want an extra entry for storing `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you would need to allocate one more entry when defining `leftHalf` and `rightHalf`.
- The assignment `leftHalf[i] = inputArr[p+i-1];` will evaluate `inputArr[p-1]` when `i` is zero, but that is an index that is outside the left partition, and could even be -1 (when `p` is 0), which is what your exception is complaining about. This should be `inputArr[p+i]`. Similarly, the next statement should assign an index that is one greater.
- The final "merge" loop starts with a wrong value for `k`. This `k` should not start at 0, but at `p`. Secondly, it should not stop *before* reaching `r`, but include `r` as well.

Here is your `merge` function with corrections for the above issues:

```
    public static void merge(int[] inputArr, int p, int q, int r) {
        int n1 = q-p+1;
        int n2 = r-q;
        int[] leftHalf = new int[n1 + 1]; // Corrected: need one extra entry
        int[] rightHalf = new int[n2 + 1]; // Corrected: need one extra entry
        for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            leftHalf[i] = inputArr[p+i]; // Corrected: start at inputArr[p]
        for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
            rightHalf[i] = inputArr[q+1+i]; // Corrected: start at inputArr[q+1]
        leftHalf[n1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // Corrected: use last slot
        rightHalf[n2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // Corrected: use last slot
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int k = p; k <= r; k++) { // Corrected: start at p, end at r
            if(leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j]){
                inputArr[k] = leftHalf[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                inputArr[k] = rightHalf[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that all these bugs can be found by meticulous debugging: stepping through the code, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, possibly printing them.

### Using `MAX_VALUE`?

As noted in comments: although the use of `MAX_VALUE` as "stopper" value simplifies the merge part of your code a bit, this requires that the input will not have this value as actual data value. If `MAX_VALUE` is considered a valid data value (and why not?), you cannot really use this shortcut, and would better do it without:

```
    public static void merge(int[] inputArr, int p, int q, int r) {
        int n1 = q-p+1;
        int n2 = r-q;
        int[] leftHalf = new int[n1];
        int[] rightHalf = new int[n2];
        for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            leftHalf[i] = inputArr[p+i];
        for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
            rightHalf[i] = inputArr[q+1+i];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int k = p; k <= r; k++) {
            // Boundary checks instead of relying on MAX_VALUE:
            if(i < n1 && (j == n2 || leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j])) {
                inputArr[k] = leftHalf[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                inputArr[k] = rightHalf[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, @greybeard, that is a valid point: including `MAX_VALUE` as actual input value will break the asker's idea to use this as a "stopper" special value.

Comment: Added the variant of the code that does not treat `MAX_VALUE` as a "stopper" value.